# Change user mail property with ADSI in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, adsi, email-address

I am trying to update the email address of a directory user with PowerShell.

I am unable to modify the mail property of a user entry with the following code:

```
$BadUser = [adsi] $Account.Path

$BadUser.mail.Clear()
$BadUser.mail.Add($User.Email) | Out-Null

$BadUser.SetInfo()
```

The mail.Clear() nor the mail.Add() seem to modify $BadUser when debugging with PowerGUI.

I have a working version that relies on the QAD plugin, and I would like to avoid using it if possible.

```
$suf = $AD.Parent.Substring(10)

Connect-QADService -Service "$($AD.dc[0]).$suf" -ErrorVariable AD_Conn_Error -ErrorAction Stop -WarningAction Stop | Out-Null

Set-QADObject $Account.Properties.distinguishedname[0] -ObjectAttributes @{mail=$User.Email} | Out-Null

Disconnect-QADService
```

Reasons I am avoiding QAD:

- I am searching for users across 8 domain servers
- ADSI allows me to save multiple connected entries in a list
- QAD can connect to 1 domain at a time
- ADSI seems relatively fast
- QAD has memory leaks (1kB/s bad) that crash in large batches
- <strike>QAD is unable to "identify" some users that ADSI found by cn</strike>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some example code to do it:

```
$query= "(&(objectCategory=User)(cn=FirstName LastName))"
$OU = "LDAP://OU=Users,dc=subdomain,dc=company,dc=com"
$PageSize = 100
$objOU = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry($OU)
$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$objSearcher.SearchRoot = $objOU
$objSearcher.PageSize = $PageSize 
$objSearcher.Filter = $query
$objSearcher.SearchScope = "Subtree"
$colResults = $objSearcher.FindAll()
foreach($objResult in $colResults) {
    $dirObject = [ADSI]$objResult.GetDirectoryEntry()
    $dirObject.mail = "newaddress@company.com"
    $dirObject.CommitChanges()
}
```

Comment: Even though mail is a collection you have to assign a string directly to it... Counter-intuitive. Thanks.

Comment: @JaredDeckard `mail` isn't a collection. `mail` is kind of a strange property because it's not used for mail routing in Exchange. The one that is a collection and used in mail routing is `proxyAddresses`